# How can I join two tables in Django and use the result in my template?

Tags: python, mysql, django, foreign-keys

I am having a hard time utilizing a foreign key in Django 1.7.  For reference:

**models.py** looks like this:

```
from django.db import models

class Transaction(models.Model):
    transaction_num = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    customer_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    transaction_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    est_pickup_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'transaction'

        def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
            return str(self.transaction_num)

class Item(models.Model):
    itemid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    transaction_num = models.ForeignKey(Transaction, db_column='transaction_num')
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    picked_up_on = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'item'

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return str(self.itemid)

class TransactionNote(models.Model):
    noteid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    transaction_num = models.ForeignKey(Transaction, db_column='transaction_num')
    content = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'transaction_note'

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return str(self.noteid)
```

**views.py** looks like this:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from pickup.models import Transaction, Item, TransactionNote

# Current Inventory
def history(request):
    t = Transaction.objects.all().order_by('-transaction_date', '-transaction_num')

    return render(request, 'pickup/history.html', { 'transaction_list': t})
```

...and the relevant part of **history.html**, a table inside of a loop, where I want to include the count of all of the related items attached to a particular transaction:

```
{% for transaction in transaction_list %}

[...]

<td>{{ transaction.customer_name }}</td>
<td>{{ transaction.transaction_date }}</td>
<td>{{ transaction.est_pickup_date }}</td>
<td>{{ transaction.phone }}</td>
<td>{{ transaction.itemid.count }}</td>

[...]

{% endfor %}
```

Everything works except for that last line.  I have no idea how to join the Transaction and Item tables so that I can work with the relevant item objects (specifically the descriptions or their counts) inside of the template.  Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django provides the ability to query all reverse relationships for an object.

To achieve this, Django provides what is consider a 'related_name' for a reverse relationship object, and it is defaulted to the class name with '_set' appended.

So, your code should look something like this,

```
{% for item in transaction.item_set.all %}
... do stuff ...
{% endfor %}
```

or

```
{{ transaction.item_set.count }}
```

Neither of these are tested, but I believe it should work closely to that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use

```
<td>{{ transaction.item_set.count }}</td>
```

not `transaction.itemid.count}}` to get number of items for transaction. Django adds `<modelname>_set` member to reverse access foreignkey field.